# codeigniter form validation can't set_rules if using a config file

Tags: validation, codeigniter-2

My config file with my validation rules works fine when calling the form_validation->run('form'). The thing is that I want to **set custom error message for one of the fields**. So in the controller I just add: ..set_message('field','message'). But it's not registering, I get the default error message: .... is required.

Answer (score 0):

For changing the message for the existing validation rules, just do the following.

1. Copy the form_validation_lang.php file from system/language/english to application/language/english
2. Modify the message for your validation rule name.

For example for changing message for required field change the below line.

```
    $lang['required']           = "The %s field is required.";
```

Comment: I mean for each field, not each rule.

Comment: Field name is passed in parameter and appear where you have %s. Do you want to have complete different messages per field. I think then you might need to have custom validation rules.

Comment: Yea. I think that's the only way. But a custom error message should be a feature as a field in the config file.